# How to pass data into ajax using codeigniter?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm current used Codeigniter and I want to create notification on menu 
In Controller

```
class Notes extends Frontend_controller{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index(){

        $this->data['data'] = array(
            'fuck'=>'fuck',
            'fucks'=>'fuckf',
            'fuckf'=>'fucks',
        );
        $this->load->view('templates/notification/notification',$this->data);
    }
}
```

Here is I echo data to view 
In View

```
    <li>
       <?PHP foreach($data as $data ){
        echo $data;
      } ?>
   </li>
```

finally I call in Jquery ajax

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var data = document.getElementsByTagName("li").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?PHP echo base_url("/notes/notes") ?>",
            data: data,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'html',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function(res) {
                $("#notes").html(res);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Result I got an errors as below

How can I do now Please help
***Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have not included JQuery in your code

Comment: Oh you are right because I put jquery library below of Ajax calling thanks